# How to perform Spring LDAP and JPA transactions

Tags: java, spring, jpa, ldap

I prefer using JPA Entitymanager factory obtain via LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean for persistence.
But I hit the wall when I want to support transaction between spring ldap and JPA. My service layer is calling both LDAP dao and JPA dao.
spring ldap has ContextSourceAndHibernateTransactionManager which requires sessionFactory 
and it doesn't have ContextSourceAndJPATransactionManager
When I use ContextSourceAndDataSourceTransactionManager with the same datasource configured for LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, it doesn't even persist a record!

I am not sure if I can use JTATransactionManager as LDAP is not XA capable.

My interim solution is to use JPATransactionManager on DAO layer and use LDAPTransactionManager on service layer. And make sure that JPA DAO is called last in service layer.

I can provide code fragments if you want.
Thanks

Comment: I am trying to perform distributed transaction between spring LDAP and Database which is accessed through JPA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point 6.3 of [spring-ldap-1.3.1 documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/transactions.html) tells to use 
ContextSourceAndDataSourceTransactionManager for 'jdbc-and-ldap' tx purposes. [spring-ldap-core-1.3.1](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.ldap%7Cspring-ldap-core%7C1.3.1.RELEASE%7Cjar) also has a ContextSourceAndHibernateTransactionManager.

Looking to this two, one can easily create his own 
ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionManager
and configure it as

```
<bean id="jpaUnderLdapTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.ldap.transaction.compensating.manager.ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="contextSource" ref="ldapSimpleContextSource"/>
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jpaUnderLdapTransactionManager"/>
```

have fun!

p.s. I almost forgot

```
public class ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionManager extends JpaTransactionManager
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private ContextSourceTransactionManagerDelegate ldapManagerDelegate =
        new ContextSourceTransactionManagerDelegate();

/**
 * @see org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager#isExistingTransaction(Object)
 */
protected boolean isExistingTransaction(Object transaction)
{
    ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionObject actualTransactionObject =
            (ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionObject) transaction;

    return super.isExistingTransaction(actualTransactionObject
                                               .getJpaTransactionObject());
}

/**
 * @see org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager#doGetTransaction()
 */
protected Object doGetTransaction() throws TransactionException
{
    Object dataSourceTransactionObject = super.doGetTransaction();
    Object contextSourceTransactionObject =
            ldapManagerDelegate.doGetTransaction();

    return new ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionObject(
            contextSourceTransactionObject, dataSourceTransactionObject
    );
}

/**
 * @see org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager#doBegin(java.lang.Object,
 *      org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition)
 */
protected void doBegin(Object transaction, TransactionDefinition definition)
        throws TransactionException
{
    ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionObject actualTransactionObject =
            (ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionObject) transaction;

    super.doBegin(actualTransactionObject.getJpaTransactionObject(),
                  definition);
    ldapManagerDelegate.doBegin(
            actualTransactionObject.getLdapTransactionObject(),
            definition
    );
}

/**
 * @see org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager#doCleanupAfterCompletion(java.lang.Object)
 */
protected void doCleanupAfterCompletion(Object transaction)
{
    ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionObject actualTransactionObject =
            (ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionObject) transaction;

    super.doCleanupAfterCompletion(actualTransactionObject
                                           .getJpaTransactionObject());
    ldapManagerDelegate.doCleanupAfterCompletion(actualTransactionObject
                                                 .getLdapTransactionObject());
}

/**
 * @see org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager#doCommit(org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus)
 */
protected void doCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status)
        throws TransactionException
{

    ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionObject actualTransactionObject =
            (ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionObject) status.getTransaction();

    try
    {
        super.doCommit(new DefaultTransactionStatus(
                actualTransactionObject.getJpaTransactionObject(),
                status.isNewTransaction(),
                status.isNewSynchronization(),
                status.isReadOnly(),
                status.isDebug(),
                status.getSuspendedResources())
        );
    }
    catch (TransactionException ex)
    {
        if (isRollbackOnCommitFailure())
        {
            logger.debug("Failed to commit db resource, rethrowing", ex);
            // If we are to rollback on commit failure, just rethrow the
            // exception - this will cause a rollback to be performed on
            // both resources.
            throw ex;
        }
        else
        {
            logger.warn(
                    "Failed to commit and resource is rollbackOnCommit not set -"
                            + " proceeding to commit ldap resource.");
        }
    }
    ldapManagerDelegate.doCommit(new DefaultTransactionStatus(
            actualTransactionObject.getLdapTransactionObject(),
            status.isNewTransaction(),
            status.isNewSynchronization(),
            status.isReadOnly(),
            status.isDebug(),
            status.getSuspendedResources())
    );
}

/**
 * @see org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager#doRollback(org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus)
 */
protected void doRollback(DefaultTransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException
{
    ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionObject actualTransactionObject =
            (ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionObject) status.getTransaction();

    super.doRollback(new DefaultTransactionStatus(
            actualTransactionObject.getJpaTransactionObject(),
            status.isNewTransaction(),
            status.isNewSynchronization(),
            status.isReadOnly(),
            status.isDebug(),
            status.getSuspendedResources())
    );
    ldapManagerDelegate.doRollback(new DefaultTransactionStatus(
            actualTransactionObject.getLdapTransactionObject(),
            status.isNewTransaction(),
            status.isNewSynchronization(),
            status.isReadOnly(),
            status.isDebug(),
            status.getSuspendedResources())
    );
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public ContextSource getContextSource()
{
    return ldapManagerDelegate.getContextSource();
}

public void setContextSource(ContextSource contextSource)
{
    ldapManagerDelegate.setContextSource(contextSource);
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
protected void setRenamingStrategy(TempEntryRenamingStrategy renamingStrategy)
{
    ldapManagerDelegate.setRenamingStrategy(renamingStrategy);
}

private final static class ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionObject
{
    private Object ldapTransactionObject;

    private Object jpaTransactionObject;

    public ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionObject(
            Object ldapTransactionObject, Object jpaTransactionObject)
    {
        this.ldapTransactionObject = ldapTransactionObject;
        this.jpaTransactionObject = jpaTransactionObject;
    }

    public Object getJpaTransactionObject()
    {
        return jpaTransactionObject;
    }

    public Object getLdapTransactionObject()
    {
        return ldapTransactionObject;
    }
}

/**
 * @see org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager#doSuspend(java.lang.Object)
 */
protected Object doSuspend(Object transaction) throws TransactionException
{
    throw new TransactionSuspensionNotSupportedException(
            "Transaction manager [" + getClass().getName()
                    + "] does not support transaction suspension");
}

/**
 * @see org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager#doResume(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
 */
protected void doResume(Object transaction, Object suspendedResources)
        throws TransactionException
{
    throw new TransactionSuspensionNotSupportedException(
            "Transaction manager [" + getClass().getName()
                    + "] does not support transaction suspension");
}

/**
 * @see org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager#doSetRollbackOnly(org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus)
 */
@Override
protected void doSetRollbackOnly(DefaultTransactionStatus status)
{
    super.doSetRollbackOnly(
            new DefaultTransactionStatus(
                ((ContextSourceAndJpaTransactionObject)status.getTransaction())
                        .getJpaTransactionObject(),
                status.isNewTransaction(),
                status.isNewSynchronization(),
                status.isReadOnly(),
                status.isDebug(),
                status.getSuspendedResources())

    );
}
}
```